# Specify a default value when a value gained from a form is not available

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a query in Access 2010 which uses a value from a form as one of its criteria:

```
WHERE (Contactnames.[Email status])=[Forms]![Reports]![Email status] OR [Forms]![Reports]![Email status])="All statuses"
```

If an option is chosen from the drop down box `Email status`, which contains "Valid", "Invalid", "Unsubscribed" etc, the query matches records with that value; if "All statuses" is selected, you get all the records.

This works as long as the form is open. However, if the form isn't open, the query of course can't find the value and asks for user input.

Is there any way of specifying a default value if the form that would normally provide the value isn't open? I'm happy to work with VBA if this goes beyond the normal capabilities of Access' SQL engine.

**EDIT:** As a workaround, I've created a duplicate query but without the filter condition that I can call when that Form isn't in use, but I'd still value a more elegant answer than that.

Comment: Have you tried using your form to recreate your saved query as a querydef? That way your `WHERE` clause could refer to the actual data last selected in your `Email status` drop down rather than referencing the form.

Comment: @MattHall - I haven't come across QueryDefs before, so I'll check that out. Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, all saved queries are represented in VBA as QueryDef objects. So, if you see query called MyQuery in the Navigation Pane, the following VBA will work:
`Debug.Print CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyQuery").Sql`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a global function. In a standard module, enter code:

```
Public Function GetReportsEmailStatus() As Variant
    Dim oControl As Access.Control
    On Error Resume Next        
    Set oControl = Application.Forms("Reports").Controls("Email status")
    If Err = 0 Then
        GetReportsEmailStatus = oControl.Value
    Else
        GetReportsEmailStatus = "All statuses"
    End If
End Function
```

Then, in your query:

```
WHERE (Contactnames.[Email status]) = GetReportsEmailStatus() 
OR GetReportsEmailStatus() = "All statuses"
```

This is efficient because, in Access queries, functions with no parameters get called only once, at the start of query execution.